# How to make my pop-up card display over the landing page? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, uinavigationbar, popupmenu, dynamic-ui

I have a problem on displaying the pop-up card when clicking the specific Persistent Bottom Nav Bar button. I want to display it over the homepage. I have been trying my best to think of possible ways to implement this code. Can anyone help me?

[Expected Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A0GF.png)
[Current Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiCk5.png)

Here is my code for this Addmodal.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:proj3/homepage/homepage.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  void _showAddModal(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MyAddmodal();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const BackButton(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text(title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        actions: <Widget>[],
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Na boang nako niya!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAddmodal extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyAddmodal({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const Myhomepage(),
                    ));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              'What do you want to do?',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                primary: Color(0xff6C63FF),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 39, vertical: 5),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // Handle first menu option
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      const MyHomePage(title: 'Create Lend Listing'),
                ));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Create Lend Listing',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 16.5,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                primary: Color(0xff6C63FF),
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                // Handle second menu option
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      const MyHomePage(title: 'Create Borrow Request'),
                ));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Create Borrow Request',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 16.5,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try so set the backgroundColor of the Dialog to transparent:

```
Dialog(
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```